# validacion letras y caracteres especiales data annotations

Tags: c#, validación

tengo esta validación (la cual me permite solo letras) pero quiero que me permita usar estos caracteres (+ -).

O alguna validacion para tipo de sangre?

Codigo:
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z ]*$",ErrorMessage = "")]

Comment: ([^a-zA-Z]|(\+|\-)) o quizas [^a-zA-Z|\-|\+] funcionen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar esta expresión regular:

`^(A|B|AB|O)[+-]$`

o esta en el caso de que no importe si son mayúsculas o minúsculas:

`([AaBbOo]|[Aa][Bb])[\+-]`